# AVAudioPlayer is not working in iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an iPhone application.In this app i am using AVAudioPlayer for playing audio.
This is my code for playing the sound.

```
  NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/sound.mp3"];

    NSError* err;

    player_ = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
               [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err )
    {
    }
    else
    {
        [player_ prepareToPlay];

        [player_ play];

        int playingLoops = 0;

        player_.numberOfLoops = playingLoops;
    }
```

It is woking fine on iphone devices except iPhone5.While i run the app on iPhone 5 i get following error then app crashes.

```
2012-11-26 09:02:28.484 test[728:1dd03] <0xb0081000> Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
2012-11-26 09:02:28.484 test[728:1dd03]  <0xb0081000> Error getting     audio input  device sample rate: '!obj'
2012-11-26 09:02:28.494 test[728:1dd03]  <0xb0081000> AQMEIOManager::FindIOUnit: error '!dev'
```

Comment: Those are strange errors. I suggest looking at the settings dictionary for the player to determine if everything is correct with the sample rate.

Comment: I got the same problem...All device works except iPhone5.Did you fixed it out?? if (did) please tell me~~ thx~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing same problem giving the same error. when try to solve this problem i notice that there is no problem in code. we need to update media player or install flash player and it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add AVAudioPlayerDelegate to your .h file and following code to your .m file

```
NSString* resourcePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSError* err;
AVAudioPlayer *audioplayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: resourcePath]  error:&err];
audioplayer.delegate=self;
if( err )
{
   NSLog(@"%@",err);
}
else
{
   [audioplayer prepareToPlay];
   [audioplayer play];
}
```

This code is working for me and accept the answer if it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Anbu, try below code.At my end it's working fine.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

NSLog(@"File path is:->%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]);

NSFileManager* manager;
manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if([manager fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audiofile.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]])
{
    printf("file Exists...\n\n");
}
else
    printf("File not exist...\n\n");

NSError *er;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;

if (audioPlayer == nil)
    NSLog([er description]);                
else 
    [audioPlayer play];
```

In any concern, let me know. And, also please check your console for the full path and for file exist or not.