# AVAudioPlayer Does not work on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, avaudioplayer, iphone-5

Has anyone experienced issues with the AVAudioPlayer using an iPhone 5? My code has worked properly on the iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, and iPad (3rd gen) but it is randomly not working on the iPhone 5 now. I saw this question but no one addressed the actual issue:

[AVAudioPlayer is not working in iPhone 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558407/avaudioplayer-is-not-working-in-iphone-5)

```
NSURL *soundURL = [self urlForAlarmSong:songKey];    
NSError *err;
self.audioAlert = [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&err] autorelease];

[self.audioAlert prepareToPlay];
currentVolume=[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer].volume;
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0];

[self.audioAlert play];
```

audioAlert is an AVAudioPlayer i've declared in my header with (retain,nonatomic). The err variable is null everytime, even when it does not play on an iPhone 5. This code works flawlesly every time on an iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, and iPad (3rd gen).

Does anyone have any ideas?? Thanks

Comment: When you say its not working on the iPhone 5, do you mean that it is not playing at all or is there just no sound? Have you checked AVAudioPlayer properties (ie. currentTime, isPlaying) to make sure that it is actually playing?

Comment: Are you setting the AVAudioSession somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad

  {

  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click2"         ofType:@"mp3"]];

    NSError *error;
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error in audio player:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else

    {

     audioPlayer.delegate=self;

     [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }

   }
```

on button action,

```
-(IBAction)SoundButton:(id)sender

     {

       [audioPlayer play];

     }
```

In your .h File, don't forget to import

```
   #import  AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h
```

and add a delegate  `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the device's sound switch is not in "mute" and the volume is high enough.

Looks pretty obvious but it can save hours of stress.

Comment: [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:1.0]; forces the volume to a max so no thats not the problem

Comment: I'm not sure if it would also change the mute switch